# How can I remove all my docker images?

Tags: virtualization, docker

Sometimes I just want to clear everything out of docker, and start with a clean slate. Is there a systematic way to just remove all my Docker containers & images?

#### Containers

```
$ docker ps -a | head
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
7b055e9e5f1f        fedora:latest        /bin/sh                6 days ago          Exited (0) 6 days ago                          ecstatic_colden        
40da968258eb        fedora:latest        /bin/sh                6 days ago          Exited (127) 6 days ago                        naughty_thompson       
5be4581afad6        fedora:latest        /bin/bash              6 days ago          Exited (0) 6 days ago                          kickass_wright         
4d6c33d4be6d        fedora:latest        /bin/bash              6 days ago          Exited (0) 6 days ago                          furious_fermat         
db7a29bdbc2d        fedora:latest        /bin/bash              6 days ago          Exited (0) 6 days ago                          mad_hawking            
e6b7365690ce        fedora:latest        /bin/bash              6 days ago          Exited (0) 6 days ago                          trusting_ardinghelli   
15655c21fcd3        8018e08e6a58         /bin/sh -c 'apt-get    3 weeks ago         Exited (100) 3 weeks ago                       drunk_bardeen          
607547aabbca        f02ed0c206d5         /bin/sh -c 'apt-get    3 weeks ago         Exited (100) 3 weeks ago                       cocky_franklin         
f031f28bd29a        f02ed0c206d5         /bin/sh -c 'apt-get    3 weeks ago         Exited (100) 3 weeks ago                       stoic_mcclintock
```

#### Images

```
$ docker images -a | head
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
docker              master              266a5746d179        2 weeks ago         1.528 GB
<none>              <none>              c1f6a4b1345c        3 weeks ago         1.526 GB
<none>              <none>              6558c36ecb3f        3 weeks ago         1.526 GB
<none>              <none>              b1b7c7a6b6a7        3 weeks ago         1.24 GB
<none>              <none>              0bf9d6bf97e9        3 weeks ago         1.182 GB
<none>              <none>              48c444f1d2e7        3 weeks ago         1.182 GB
<none>              <none>              5c5c172a0038        3 weeks ago         1.182 GB
<none>              <none>              de5e09bb86c1        3 weeks ago         1.182 GB
<none>              <none>              785aaf265f18        3 weeks ago         1.182 GB
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use do the following 3 steps:

1. stop all the containers
2. remove all the containers
3. remove all the images

To achieve this you can make use of the `docker ps` and `docker images` commands abilities to just return you a list of IDs via there `-q` or `--quiet` switch. This gets rid of all the cruft that both these commands typically returns and just gives you a nice list, like so:

**Default output**

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
7b055e9e5f1f        fedora:latest        /bin/sh                6 days ago          Exited (0) 6 days ago                          ecstatic_colden        
40da968258eb        fedora:latest        /bin/sh                6 days ago          Exited (127) 6 days ago                        naughty_thompson
```

**Quiet output**

```
$ docker ps -aq
7b055e9e5f1f
40da968258eb
5be4581afad6
4d6c33d4be6d
```

**NOTE:** Both `docker images` and `docker ps` also make use of the `-a` or `--all` switch which shows you all the IDs.

You can utilize this output to construct Docker commands that make use of output from other Docker commands like so:

```
$ docker rm $(docker ps -qa)
```

#### Cleaning house

So to accomplish your task of removing everything you'd use the following commands:

```
$ docker stop $(docker ps -qa)
$ docker rm $(docker ps -qa)
$ docker rmi $(docker images -qa)
```